# Error al querer leer el último registro en archivo .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Tengo un archivo de texto que contiene lo siguiente:

> ```
> 1  123
> 2  345
> 3  567
> 4  789
> ```

Tengo que establecer el próximo código que sí o si tiene que ser 5, no puedo contar las líneas porque el programa tiene la posibilidad de borrar una línea:

> ```
> 1  123
> 2  345
> 4  789
> ```

Si cuento las lineas el código seria 3+1=4 y el 4 estaría repetido cosa que no puede ocurrir porque lo utilizo para la búsqueda.

Lo que ocurre es que si tengo más de una línea el programa funciona correctamente, pero si tengo un solo registro me da error, `tmp` aparece vacío. -

La función:

```
def establecer_codigo():
    archivo = abrir_lectura()
    tmp = archivo.readlines()[-1]
    tmp = tmp.split()
    codigo = int(tmp[0])
    archivo.close()

    return codigo
```

## Trabajar con ficheros.

## Miércoles 21 de Marzo de 2018

```
import os

def abrir_lectura():
    try:
        _archivo = open("manual_python.txt", "r")
    except:
        print(f'\n No se pudo abrir el archivo...')
    else:
        return _archivo

def abrir_escritura():
    try:
        _archivo = open("manual_python.txt", "a")
    except:
        print(f'\n No se pudo abrir el archivo...')
    else:
        return _archivo

def menu_uno():
    while True:
        print(f'\n ===== Menú principal =====')
        opc_uno = input("\n 1 - Agregar\n 2 - Buscar\n 3 - Salir\n\n Ingrese opción...: ")
        if opc_uno >= '1' and opc_uno <= '3':
            if opc_uno == '1':
                agregar()
            elif opc_uno == '2':
                buscar()
            else:
                break
        else:
            input(f'\n Ingrese opción entre "1" y "3"...'
                   '\n\t Pulse [Enter] para continuar...')
            limpiar_pantalla()

def menu_dos(linea, codigo):
    while True:
        limpiar_pantalla()
        print(f'\n ===== Menú de búsqueda =====')
        print(f'\n {linea}')
        opc = input(f'\n 1 - Modificar\n 2 - Borrar\n '
                '3 - Continuar...\n\n Ingrese opción...: ')
        if opc >= '1' and opc <= '3':
            if opc == '1':
                modificar(codigo)
            elif opc == '2':
                borrar()
            else:
                break
        else:
            input(f'\n Ingrese opción entre "1" y "3"'
                   '\n\t Pulse [Enter] para continuar...')
            limpiar_pantalla()

    limpiar_pantalla()


def agregar():
    archivo = abrir_lectura()
    if archivo:
        archivo.close()
        codigo = establecer_codigo()
        archivo = abrir_escritura() 
        codigo += 1
        archivo.close()
        archivo = abrir_escritura()
        rec = input('\n Ingrese recordatorio...:')
        archivo.write(" ".join((str(codigo) + '    ', rec)) + "\n")
    else:
        input("\n No se pudo abrir el archivo...\n"
              " Pulse [Enter] para finalizar...")

def buscar():
    archivo = abrir_lectura()
    if archivo:
        if tamanio_archivo(archivo):
            i=0
            consulta = input(f'\n Ingrese código...: ') 
            for linea in archivo:
                _codigo = linea.split()
                if len(_codigo):
                    if _codigo[0] == consulta:
                        codigo = _codigo[0]
                        i += 1  
                        archivo.close()
                        menu_dos(linea, codigo)
                        break
            if i == 0:
                print(f'\n No existe el código...: {consulta}')
                input(f'\n\t Pulse [enter] para continuar...')
                limpiar_pantalla()

            archivo.close()
        else:
            input('\n Archivo vacio...\n'
                  '\t Pulse [Enter] para agregar/salir...')
    else:
        input("\n No se pudo abrir el archivo...\n"
              " Pulse [Enter] para finalizar...")

def establecer_codigo():
    archivo = abrir_lectura()
    tmp = archivo.readlines()[-1]
    tmp = tmp.split()
    codigo = int(tmp[0])
    archivo.close()

    return codigo


def tamanio_archivo(archivo):
    tamArchi = os.stat("manual_python.txt").st_size
    return tamArchi

def limpiar_pantalla():
    if os.name == "posix":
        os.system ("clear")
    elif os.name in ("ce", "nt", "dos"):
        os.system ("cls")

def modificar(codigo):
    mod_rec = input('\n Ingrese nuevo recordatorio:')
    archivo = abrir_escritura()
    for linea in archivo:
        tmp = linea.split()
        if len(tmp):
            if codigo == tmp[0]:
                archivo.write(" ".join((str(codigo[0]) , mod_rec)))
                break

    archivo.close()

def borrar():
    print('\n borrar')

menu_uno()
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, no consigo entender cual es el problema... Si tu archivo solo tiene una línea `readlines()[-1]` debe obtenerla sin problemas tanto si tiene como si no salto de línea al final... ¿O es que el error ocurre cuando no hay nada en el archivo e intentas guardar la primera fila? Esto no debería pasar a no ser que en `abrir_lectura()` leas parte del archivo y el cursor no esté al inicio como debería (por ejemplo). Te recomiendo colocar un [mcve] para que podamos reproducir el problema.

Comment: Hola y gracias por ocuparte, me está costando porque no entiendo este foro, no encuentro como responder a tu sugerencia, estoy complicado, gracia igual

Comment: Daniel si quieres añadir información como agregar el código mínimo para reproducir el error o explicar mejor el problema que tienes simplemente edita la pregunta, para ello usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/150346/edit) que hay debajo de ella. Como te comentaba a no ser que ejecutes la función cuando el archivo está vacío la función debe funcionar sin problemas (a no ser que hagas algo en `abrir_lectura()` aparte de abrir el archivo en modo lectura). Por eso te comentaba que agregaras un ejemplo mínimo o todo tu código si es pequeño para poder ver dónde esta la causa.

Answer (score 0):

Esta versión si parece funcionar correctamente, le quite el último
salto de línea e igual no da error

```
import os
contenido = os.stat("practicas.txt").st_size
fo = open("practicas.txt", "r")

if contenido == 0:
    codigo = 0
else:
    tmp = fo.readlines()[-1]
    tmp = tmp.split()
    codigo = int(tmp[0])

fo.close()
codigo += 1
print(codigo)
```